# combining ternary with and or javascript?

Tags: javascript, conditional-operator

why is it like this?

```js
let number = 5
const result = number == 4 ? 'true 1' : 'false 1' || number == 3 ? 'true 2' : 'false 2'  || number == 5 ? 'true 3' : 'false 3'
console.log(result)
```

// return result true 2
answer true 2 why can it be like that?

Comment: [Operator precedence](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Operator_Precedence)

Comment: When you use multiple operators, use brackets. It's just easier to read. You can use [astexplorer.net](https://astexplorer.net/#/gist/9f0dc780efe97c9b01570285069f41b2/121fa379930ac3999154f5ea79aee3d1e854bab8) to check the order of execution. Expand the tree on the right side panel

Comment: sorry, English isn't smooth

I think if
'true 1' will be changed to boolean true and checked by the operator && ||
then the results match

Comment: @kmoser parenthesis is a [type of bracket](https://www.mathsisfun.com/algebra/brackets.html). In this context, I meant parenthesis.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your statement

```
const result = number == 4 ? 'true 1' : 'false 1' || number == 3 ? 'true 2' : 'false 2'  || number == 5 ? 'true 3' : 'false 3'
```

is interpreted as if it were written

```
const result = (number == 4) ? 'true 1' : ('false 1' || number == 3) ? 'true 2' : ('false 2 || number == 5) ? 'true 3' : 'false 3';
```

In particular, this part `('false 1' || number ==3)` is `true` because `'false 1'` is a non-empty string.

I am not sure what you were attempting, but note that `? :` ultimately can have just one value: either the value of the first expression, or the value of the second. Thus those `'false n'` strings really don't make any sense: either one of those conditional tests of `number` will be true, or none will be.